# Identity involving a projection matrix, originating from statistical regression theory

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, projection-matrices

I am studying multiple linear regression and I am not able to understand a passage from my statistics textbook.
The part that I do not understand can be formulated entirely in the language of linear algebra, as I will do here.

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ an $n \times m$ matrix, with $n \geq m$ and with rank $m$.
Let us denote $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ the $m$ column vectors.
Let $P$ be the $n\times n$ matrix of the linear application describing the orthogonal projection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto the $m-1$-dimensional subspace
\begin{equation*}
 \langle x_1, \ldots, x_{m-1}\rangle.
\end{equation*}
Let $I_n$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix.
Let us denote with $w^2_m$ the value at position $(m, m)$ of the $m \times m$ square matrix $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}$.
Then
\begin{equation*}
 w^2_m = \frac{1}{x_m^{\top}(I_n - P)x_m}.
\end{equation*}

Why does the last equation hold?

Probably it can be useful to know that $P$ can be written as
\begin{equation*}
P = X_0(X_0^{\top}X_0)^{-1}X_0^{\top},
\end{equation*}
where $X$ is the $n \times m-1$ matrix formed by the first $m-1$ columns of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X$ as block matrix and calculate $X^{\top}X$:
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}X_0 & x_m\end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
X^{\top}X=\begin{pmatrix}X^\top_0 \\ x^\top_m\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X_0 & x_m\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}X^\top_0X_0 & X^\top_0x_m\\ x^\top_mX_0 & x^\top_m x_m\end{pmatrix}.
$$
To find the value $w_m^2$  at position $(m,m)$ of $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}$, we need to divide determinant of $X^\top_0X_0$ by the determinant of $X^{\top}X$:
$$
w_m^2=\frac{\det(X^\top_0X_0)}{\det(X^{\top}X)}.
$$
With the help of determinant of block matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices get
$$
\det(X^{\top}X) = \textrm{det}(X^\top_0X_0)\cdot \textrm{det}\bigl(x_m^\top x_m-x_m^\top \underbrace{X_0 (X_0^\top X_0)^{-1}X_0^\top}_{P} x_m\bigr) 
$$
$$
=\det(X^\top_0X_0)\cdot \bigl(x_m^\top (I_n-P) x_m\bigr).
$$
We skip last $\det$ since matrix $x_m^\top (I_n-P) x_m$ is $1\times 1$.

Finally,
$$
w_m^2=\frac{\det(X^\top_0X_0)}{\textrm{det}(X^{\top}X)} = \frac{1}{x_m^\top (I_n-P) x_m}.
$$

Comment: I do not understand why this is valid: "To find the value $w_m$  at position $(m,m)$ of $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}$, we need to divide determinant of $X^\top_0X_0$ by the determinant of $X^{\top}X$". Can you please develop it further? Thank you

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#In_relation_to_its_adjugate

Comment: Or look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix
We need a cofactor to element $(m,m)$, and this is exactly the determinant of $X_0^\top X_0$.